# Facebook login with OmniAuth for different user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I'm using the [omniauth](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) gem to allow users to preform a facebook signup to my site.
I have two different types of Users: Students and Landlords, who have a polymorphic association with User.

```
has_one :user, as: :userable
```

I have a different signup for each and I want to add the "Facebook connect" option to both. The problem is: the facebook auth callback only routes to one controller action. 
How can I separate the callback according to which type of user is signing up? Can I know in the callback which controller action called it? Can I have to separate links for facebook signup? for example:

```
auth/facebook/student
auth/facebook/landlord
```

I'd appreciate any help or ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your facebook signup links to this:

```
auth/facebook?user=student
auth/facebook?user=landlord
```

And then, in your `facebook` action, you can do the following:

```
if request.env['omniauth.params']['user'] == 'landlord'
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks! that's a nice solution. 
I ended up using the Koala gem for authentication and there I can specify a different callback urls